# open tga files on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, tga

I dont know whether it is possible to view tga image files on asp.net?

Tga image files are not known image files for webpages, I think.

But there might be a control to view tag image files for asp.net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want ASP.NET to process the TGA images, or do you want ASP.NET to deliver TGA images to a browser to view?

Comment: yes, I want to view TGA images on asp.net.

Comment: ASP.NET is a server-side only technology. You can't "view" an image on it. You can either deliver an image for viewing in a browser, or read it, process it, then deliver it to the browser. There's a difference between those two. Which are you after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know browsers do not support TGA images.
One alternative might be plugins such as flash, silverlight, ... which I believe do support TGA images.

If plugins are not an option, you will need to convert the TGA image to a format browsers can handle, e.g. jpg.
You could use an HttpHandler for this.

This [article](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent3.aspx) shows the use of httphandlers to generate thumbnails on the fly. You can use this same approach and use a library such as [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to do the conversion and return the image in jpg format on the fly.
Here you find a [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx) explaining how to use ImageMagick within an asp.net website.